# Running heavy sparksql which is facing GC in majority of time

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm

I intend to run a heavy spark sql job (attached in the end), and it runs so long a time, I checked the executors monitor page, it shows so much GC time consumed during the execution:

[image]

but the `Storage Memory` is very low. Then I go to stage monitor page, all the running tasks have high GC time:

[image]

[image]

The code is as follows, could anyone give me a way/direction to debug/tweak/tune on this scenario? Thanks!

```
object etaWithSpeed {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                              .appName("etaWithSpeed")
                              .config("num-executors", 15)
                              .config("executor-memory", 4)
                              .enableHiveSupport()
                              .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

    import ch.hsr.geohash.{WGS84Point, GeoHash, BoundingBox}
    import math._
    import scala.annotation.tailrec

    def haversine(lat1:Double, lon1:Double, lat2:Double, lon2:Double)={
      val dLat=(lat2 - lat1).toRadians
      val dLon=(lon2 - lon1).toRadians

      val a = pow(sin(dLat/2),2) + pow(sin(dLon/2),2) * cos(lat1.toRadians) * cos(lat2.toRadians)
      val c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a))
      6372.8 * c
    }

    def geohash(lat: Double, lon: Double)={
      GeoHash.withBitPrecision(lat, lon, 30).toBase32
    }

    def geohash_grid_expand(geohash: String)={
      GeoHash.fromGeohashString(geohash).getAdjacent().map(_.toBase32) :+ geohash
    }

    def geohash_envelope_between_two_grid(lat1: Double, lon1: Double, lat2: Double, lon2: Double): List[String] = {

      val gh1 = GeoHash.withBitPrecision(lat1, lon1, 30)
      val gh2 = GeoHash.withBitPrecision(lat2, lon2, 30)

      // MARK: decide border
      val sortedLons = List(gh1.getBoundingBox.getMaxLon, gh1.getBoundingBox.getMinLon, gh2.getBoundingBox.getMaxLon, gh2.getBoundingBox.getMinLon).sorted
      var lonMin = 0.0
      var lonMax = 0.0
      var kind = 0
      if(abs(gh1.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLongitude-gh2.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLongitude) <= 180.0)  {
        lonMin = sortedLons(0)
        lonMax = sortedLons(3)
        kind = 0
      }
      else  {
        lonMin = sortedLons(1)
        lonMax = sortedLons(2)
        kind = 1
      }
      val sortedLats = List(gh1.getBoundingBox.getMinLat, gh1.getBoundingBox.getMaxLat, gh2.getBoundingBox.getMinLat, gh2.getBoundingBox.getMaxLat).sorted
      var latMin = sortedLats.min
      var latMax = sortedLats.max

      def withinEnvelope(ghCur: GeoHash): Boolean = {
        val ghCurLon = ghCur.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLongitude
        val ghCurLat = ghCur.getBoundingBoxCenterPoint.getLatitude
        if(ghCurLat >= latMin && ghCurLat <= latMax)  {
          if(kind == 0 && ghCurLon >= lonMin && ghCurLon <= lonMax) {
            true
          }
          else if(kind == 1 && (ghCurLon <= lonMin || ghCurLon >= lonMax)) {
            true
          }
          else  {
            false
          }
        }
        else  {
          false
        }
      }

      @tailrec
      def expand_neighbors_impl(toGoThrough: List[GeoHash], buffer: Set[GeoHash] = Set()): Set[GeoHash] = {
        toGoThrough.headOption match {
          case None => buffer
          case Some(ghCur) =>
            if (buffer contains ghCur) {
              expand_neighbors_impl(toGoThrough.tail, buffer)
            }
            else {
              val neighbors = get4GeoHashAround(ghCur).filter(withinEnvelope(_))
              expand_neighbors_impl(neighbors ++: toGoThrough, buffer + ghCur)
            }
        }
      }

      def expand_neighbors(): Set[GeoHash] = expand_neighbors_impl(List(gh1))

      def get4GeoHashAround(gh: GeoHash): Array[GeoHash] = {
        Array(gh.getNorthernNeighbour, gh.getSouthernNeighbour, gh.getWesternNeighbour, gh.getEasternNeighbour)
      }

      expand_neighbors.toList.map(_.toBase32)
    }

    spark.sqlContext.udf.register("haversine", haversine _)
    spark.sqlContext.udf.register("geohash", geohash _)
    spark.sqlContext.udf.register("geohash_grid_expand", geohash_grid_expand _)
    spark.sqlContext.udf.register("geohash_envelope_between_two_grid", geohash_envelope_between_two_grid _)

    spark.sql("""with tmp1 as(
select
    ied.*,
    explode(geohash_envelope_between_two_grid(ied.latitude1, ied.longitude1, ied.latitude2, ied.longitude2)) as geohash_value
from dev_oussama.inhouse_eta_data ied
)
select
    tmp1.time,
    tmp1.latitude1,
    tmp1.longitude1,
    tmp1.latitude2,
    tmp1.longitude2,
    tmp1.google_eta,
    tmp1.booking_id,
    tmp1.user_id,
    tmp1.real_eta,
    tmp1.osm_eta,
    tmp1.osm_distance,
    tmp1.osm_api_result,
    sum(gr.avg_speed_mps*gr.no_of_driver_ping)/sum(gr.no_of_driver_ping) as avg_speed_mps
from tmp1
join dev_jason_zhu.geohash_region_metrics gr on tmp1.geohash_value = gr.geohash_value
group by
    tmp1.time,
    tmp1.latitude1,
    tmp1.longitude1,
    tmp1.latitude2,
    tmp1.longitude2,
    tmp1.google_eta,
    tmp1.booking_id,
    tmp1.user_id,
    tmp1.real_eta,
    tmp1.osm_eta,
    tmp1.osm_distance,
    tmp1.osm_api_result
limit 1000""").show()
  }

}
```

**P.S.**
When I try monitoring instances in heap in a specific java process, the following is printed. Obviously, there's a lot of `GeoHash` related objects, any way to solve it somehow?

```
bash-4.2$ jmap -histo:live 19808 | head

 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:          6199      155188800  [B
   2:           591      101908160  [J
   3:        766706       36801888  ch.hsr.geohash.BoundingBox
   4:        766706       24534592  ch.hsr.geohash.GeoHash
   5:        766706       24534592  ch.hsr.geohash.WGS84Point
   6:        766876       18405024  scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
   7:        219583        5269992  scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1
```

**stdout log from a executor**

```
2017-04-15T07:41:06.702+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:06.702+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.1675930 secs] 2717803K->2474880K(6257408K), 0.1676444 secs] [Times: user=0.65 sys=0.00, real=0.17 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:06.991+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:06.991+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.2082425 secs] 2747520K->2511759K(6257408K), 0.2082937 secs] [Times: user=0.80 sys=0.00, real=0.21 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:07.318+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:07.318+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.1989878 secs] 2784399K->2560107K(6257408K), 0.1990396 secs] [Times: user=0.76 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:07.636+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:07.636+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.2265302 secs] 2832747K->2614298K(6257408K), 0.2265810 secs] [Times: user=0.87 sys=0.00, real=0.22 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:07.981+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:07.981+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.1750708 secs] 2886938K->2657702K(6257408K), 0.1751232 secs] [Times: user=0.66 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:08.273+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:08.273+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.2805720 secs] 2930342K->2710186K(6257408K), 0.2806221 secs] [Times: user=1.09 sys=0.00, real=0.28 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:08.672+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:08.672+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34046K(306688K), 0.1939371 secs] 2982826K->2759971K(6257408K), 0.1940055 secs] [Times: user=0.74 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:08.985+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:08.985+0000: [ParNew: 306686K->34046K(306688K), 0.1824374 secs] 3032611K->2803546K(6257408K), 0.1824884 secs] [Times: user=0.70 sys=0.00, real=0.18 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:09.286+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:09.286+0000: [ParNew: 306686K->34046K(306688K), 0.2459598 secs] 3076186K->2862064K(6257408K), 0.2460109 secs] [Times: user=0.95 sys=0.00, real=0.24 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:09.650+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:09.650+0000: [ParNew: 306686K->34048K(306688K), 0.2248917 secs] 3134704K->2916068K(6257408K), 0.2249424 secs] [Times: user=0.87 sys=0.00, real=0.23 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:09.994+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:09.994+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.1995261 secs] 3188708K->2963537K(6257408K), 0.1995778 secs] [Times: user=0.77 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:10.312+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:10.312+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.2394581 secs] 3236177K->3013025K(6257408K), 0.2395090 secs] [Times: user=0.91 sys=0.01, real=0.24 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:10.675+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:10.675+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34048K(306688K), 0.2054829 secs] 3285665K->3065302K(6257408K), 0.2055344 secs] [Times: user=0.78 sys=0.00, real=0.20 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:10.999+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:10.999+0000: [ParNew: 306688K->34046K(306688K), 0.2380438 secs] 3337942K->3122984K(6257408K), 0.2380944 secs] [Times: user=0.91 sys=0.00, real=0.24 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:11.360+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:11.360+0000: [ParNew: 306686K->34046K(306688K), 0.2232903 secs] 3395624K->3177798K(6257408K), 0.2233435 secs] [Times: user=0.85 sys=0.00, real=0.23 secs] 
2017-04-15T07:41:11.703+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-04-15T07:41:11.703+0000: [ParNew: 306686K->34046K(306688K), 0.1517400 secs] 3450438K->3215043K(6257408K), 0.1517907 secs] [Times: user=0.58 sys=0.00, real=0.14 secs] 
20
```

Comment: That probably means that either your JVM heap is too small or you don't have enough physical RAM on your machine.  Based on the GC log, it is probably the former.

Comment: I've increased `executor-memory` from 4g to 8g, not gc time only occupies 40% of all running time, but the job itself if still make no progress from the progress bar, any suggestions? @StephenC

Comment: Not sure how big your table data but suggest to optimize your query if you can...increase the number of partitions so your job will distribute more to reduce worker overhead....increase in executor-memory may not help in many cases